SWUP, GIA, WordPress and Plugins
I've build a WordPress website that uses SWUP and GIA, All works fine except for when a plugin shortcode is on a page, namely the Smash Balloon Instagram Feed.
I have tried adding a component to the page that gets the script from the plugin like so

    // Get the root domain
    var rootDomain = this.getRootDomain();

    // Construct the URL with the root domain
    var scriptUrl = "https://" + rootDomain + "/wp-content/plugins/instagram-feed/js/sbi-scripts.min.js";


    // Set the source of the external script
    script.src = scriptUrl;

    // Append the script element to the head of the document
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    // Optionally, you can add a callback function to execute after the script has loaded
    script.onload = function () {
      console.log("External script loaded successfully");
    };

    // Optionally, you can handle errors if the script fails to load
    script.onerror = function () {
      console.error("Failed to load external script");
    };
  }


It's all fine on initial load as it's on the home page, but when I navigate back to the home page, it's blank. I get a console log saying the script is loaded successfully.
Has anyone had any luck triggering plugin scripts after a page transition? Is going the AJAX route the best way?
